# Updating model values in custom model binder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-model-binder

I have a custom model binder which adds some properties to my model.

It all works fine when adding properties to it, but is I to to update any of the existing properties, it seems those get ignored.

My code is as follows:

**controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Add(Deal model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model = _taskHelper.AddOrUpdateDeal(model);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

**model binder**

```
public class DealModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder 
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.Type modelType)
    {
        if (modelType != typeof (Deal)) 
            return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);

        // Capture deal code
        var dealCode = (string)bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("DealCode").ConvertTo(typeof(string));
        // Create a short URL for the deal
        var shortUrl = "";
        if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(dealCode, UriKind.Absolute))
        {
            // hardcoded for brevity
            shortUrl = "http://amzn.to/1EDZm1r";
        }


        return new Deal()
        {
            DealCode = "XXXXX", // this never updates
            DealNick = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["DealNick"] // this also never updates,
            Price = Convert.ToDouble(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Price"]) //this and the below start off empty so update fine,
            Url = shortUrl,
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now
        };
    }
}
```

Notice the comments on the code, which has been modified for brevity. In summary, anything that doesn't get set initially when the form is submitted can be updated without issues. Anything that is set initially, just doesn't get updated.

Thanks